# How may i apply sleep functionality on array in Ruby on rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, whenever

I am working on a project in rails where i have used pluck

```html
 @employees = Employee.where.not("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')).pluck(:email)
 
 mail(to: @employees, subject: 'Birthday Invitation')
 
 when i am sending email using Whenever gems,email is not going.I am getting Rake aborted error
```

so how may i send email to more emp.

Comment: if i apply loop and send email,then email is only going to last employee in the loop.I want to make the loop wait for 2 sec and send email to employee,and the loop will only exit if email is sent to all the employee.This all i am doing with whenever gem.

Comment: @employees.each do |employee|
mail(to: employee, subject: 'Birthday Invitation')
end

Something like this should work. Best if you use delayed job.

Comment: I have tried this...But email only goes to last person in loop...I want it to be sent to everyone....And what I delayed job...hows it???

Comment: if u have any idea then pls help .............. @puneet

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

## mailer

```
def birthday_email
  date = Date.today 
    @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')).where("age > 21")
    @employees.find_in_batches(batch_size: 20) do |group|
      group.each { |emp| mail(to: emp.email, subject: 'Birthday Wishes'); sleep 3;}
      sleep 5
    end

end
```

Comment: i tried your solution,still i'm getting same error. rake aborted!
Net::SMTPServerBusy: 452 4.5.3 Error: too many recipients

Comment: have you used such functionality in any of ur application....so that i may get the syntax............

Comment: How much time will it take to send email for 500 employees....coz there is no error in the log file....!!!!!! how may i check whether email is gon or not....i have updated my emil id....still email is not received...........!!!!!

Comment: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.

Comment: And about if i want to apply this functionality for a method in controller,means i have wrriten an method in controller which i want to execute at a time which i specify in my schedule file..........