# How may i apply Export to Text functionality in rails

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

Using Rails 4,i want to apply import and export functionality,when i click on EXPORT TO TEXT link all my table data which is present in table is downloaded to text. Same functionality i have applied for excel but now i want it for text.So i don't have any idea on how may i do it and what i may write in controller.

```html
This is my previous code which i have followed from railcast.

def import_machine_attendance
  @emp = Employee.all
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @emp.to_csv }
      format.xls
  end
end

<%= link_to "CSV", import_machine_attendance_machine_attendances_path(format: "csv") %> |
```

Comment: whats the solution?????

Comment: please refer https://gorails.com/episodes/export-to-csv

Comment: i have an export to csv functionality,but now i wants export to text format in which each row may be separated from other by delimiter #

Comment: name#age#first_name#last_name

Comment: abc#20#abc#xyzz

Comment: its similar to csv but now i want afile to be generated which may be separated by hash (#) like above what i explained.

Comment: you can use export to csv functionality with '#' separator. you can set any separator you want.

Comment: will you let me know where i may set seperator???? this i have wriiten in my model

Comment: def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |emp|
        csv << emp.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with override `to_csv`,

```
def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id email name}

    CSV.generate(:col_sep => "#") do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |employee|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| employee.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: in my model it is def self.to_csv(options = {}),may i replace this with CSV.generate(:col_sep => "#") do |csv|

Comment: thnaks it worked. will you also answer my question if you know the solution which i previously posted...???? following is the link....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920570/preview-documents-in-iframe-in-rails

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873678/how-may-i-apply-sleep-functionality-on-array-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: this data is coming from a single table.what if i want the data to be accessed from multiple table. for i want the department name of any employee then how may i write??????????

Comment: this is in the format attributes = %w{id email name}   but when i write attributes = %w{id email id.department.name}  i am getting the error.So how may i access the data from other table and write it in attributes.

Comment: how's its possible to get the data from datatables,via references......so is there any way i may get data from multiple table using the above method as you described....but in that i also want to add some dropdowns....like month and year.... month = params[:pf_detail][:month]
                              year = params[:pf_detail][:year]   like this....so i may get the data for this month and year.............

Comment: it is not necessary to set attributes as i describe in example you can made your own logic.

Comment: do you know the solution of this??????????????????????       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358767/sending-pdf-via-email-in-rails

Comment: i want to send pdf to every employee which i select in a checkbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025173/issue-in-rake-dbload-command-while-switching-to-mysql-database   @hardik pls reply if you know the solution.............

Comment: this is the link of my new question............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038387/how-may-i-copy-all-my-existing-application-data-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails

Comment: its very urgent bro.....all my application has stopped working.............