# How may I copy all my existing application Data from sqlite3 to MySQL in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am working on a project in Rails 4. I was using sqlite3 database previously. But now I want to switch the database from sqlite3 to mysql. But all my previous application data should be copied so when I use mysql database none of my table data may be deleted.

Comment: i am getting the error whenever i am running rake db:schema:load

Answer (score 1):

### try this

```
1. cd /path/to/rails_app/db

2. sqlite3 DATA-BASE-NAME .dump > database.sql

3. mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < database.sql
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: ok i will try it and update............thanks.......... :)

Comment: i am successful in changing my database...but some another method....but now i am facing issue in one of my file using strftime query.......i have posted one question.......rply in that if you know..........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4

Comment: @Hardik...........................thanks........ :)

Comment: i have upvoted you....you also upvote me in all my questions....!!!