# strftime error while switching my database from sqlite3 to mysql in Rails4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

Recently i changed my database from sqlite3 to mysql.When i ran my project i am getting this error in one of the file which is using this query.

date = Date.today + 1

@employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')

```html
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION hrms_development.strftime does not exist: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `employees` WHERE (status = 'Active' AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = '28/03')):
    210:             
    211:               <% date = Date.today %>
    212:              <% @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')) %>
    213:             <% if @employees.empty? %>
    214:              
    215:             <%else%>
    216:               <% @employees.each do |e| %>
  app/views/home/_group_admin.html.erb:213:in `_app_views_home__group_admin_html_erb___2522183600721478262_91627100'
  app/views/home/index.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__2772204906267359422_86967120'



ActionView::Template::Error: Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION hrms_development.strftime does not exist: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `employees` WHERE (status = 'Active' AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = '28/03')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with simply replace,

```
<% @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')) %>
```

With

```
<% @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth,'%d/%m') = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')) %>
```

Comment: i am getting this error on windows when i am running my project and doing rake db:migrate

Comment: D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': Could no
t load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. I
f you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfil
e. (LoadError)

Comment: Everthing works fine on Linux ubuntu,only on windows i am getting this error.

Comment: you need to install mysql in windows machine..as well

Comment: i am having problem while exporting my datababase in mysql, i have alo ran mysqldump -h [host] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql then database.sql,and also source database.sql still no data in tables??????

Comment: sorry i can't understand your issue.

Comment: and one more thing you need to import data from .sql file currently you are exporting data

Comment: ya i am importing data....i am using mysqldump -h [host] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name < db_backup.sql an database.sql file contains all the insert command.But on running source database.sql command 0 row affected is coming.

Comment: will you please let me know in step by step how may i copy database.sql file to database.

Comment: and get all the data in the tables.

Comment: i am getting Dump completed message,but not getting data in the table.

Comment: first drop and recreate your database then after run this command mysql -u username -p database_name < database.sql

Comment: but database.sql is the file which i have tken from another pc......and i have placed it in db folder.....for that file i need to create dump....and insert all enteries in database.

Comment: i am successful in copying mysql database...will you upvote me...so that i may increase my reputatiion here...

Comment: in athis question you can upvote me............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088609/replace-mysql-database-from-one-computer-to-other-in-rails-as-we-do-in-sqlite3/43088706?noredirect=1#comment73263572_43088706 and also on other questions....!!!!!!

Comment: i have posted one question...help me....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109523/how-may-i-switch-my-rails-app-from-mysql-to-sql-server-in-rails-4-in-windows   @Hardik

Answer (score 0):

There is no strftime function in MySQL. Use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) instead.

See [Convert DateTime Value into String in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392413/convert-datetime-value-into-string-in-mysql) for more examples.

Comment: Will you please provide me an example of how may i apply DATE_FORMAT in rails 4.I am new to this so don't know.

Comment: date = Date.today  @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND strftime('%d/%m', date_of_birth) = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m'))

Comment: i want to convert this query to mysql.

Comment: my new question.............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065691/mysql-error-while-running-rake-dbmigrate-in-windows       @hardik