# mysql error while running rake db:migrate in Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Project where i switched my database from sqlite3 to mysql.All configurations is done properly,but i am getting error while i am running rake db:migrate on Windows machine.

```html
PS D:\workspace\hrms> rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/datab
ase.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapte
r gem to the Gemfile.
D:/workspace/hrms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2
D:/workspace/hrms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this is my database.yml file for windows

default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ****
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
development:
  <<: *default
  database: hrms_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: hrms_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: hrms_production
  username: hrms
  password: <%= ENV['HRMS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

is it correct...or i need to include some more settings??????????????

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0/mysql2-0.4.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: Your `config/database.yml` is probably wrong. Do add it into the question

Comment: include the commands of how you add that ruby app also

Comment: default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: *****
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
development:
  <<: *default
  database: hrms_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: hrms_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: hrms_production
  username: hrms
  password: <%= ENV['HRMS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: i have included mysql using.....bundle config build.mysql2 '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"

Comment: still i am getting the error.....when i ran above command.....1 gem istalled came....

Comment: but still i am getting error while running rake db:migrate

Comment: now i am getting this error........Exiting
D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect': Unknown database
'hrms_development' (Mysql2::Error)

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons;

1. You did not specify the adapter properly in database.yml
2. You missed to add necessary gem to gem file.

Please share your rails version and can you try with 'mysql' as adapter.

Comment: i am using Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.1.9

Comment: above i have included the code for my database.yml file

Comment: gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'      gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter', '~> 0.0.3'  this all i have added in my gemfile

Comment: after that ran.........bundle config build.mysql2 '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include" ..........and was successfull.....1 gem installed came.....

Comment: will you please let me know what configuration i may specify in my database.yml file for windows....?????????????????

Comment: In Windows I too faced some challenges with gems and got corrected after downgrading the gem versions. That is why I suggested *mysql* as adapter instead of *mysql2*

Comment: Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql'` to your Gemfile (an
d ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).    this error came....when i removed 2 from mysql2...

Comment: Please do a try. Also, please check whether the link below provide any help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7

Comment: Please add gem 'mysql' to your gem-file and do bundle install then.

Comment: i am getting this error...whenever running  gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/"'