# Replace Mysql database from one Computer to Other in Rails as we do in sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

I switched to mysql dtabase in Rails.I got a databse.sql file generated in db folder.But when i login to mysql and check data in tables then there is no records present in tables.

```html
i used this command for dump

mysql –u root –p database_name < database_name.sql
```

there was no error while executing this command but when i checked the tables then there were no records in the tables.So please help me to insert all my records in database using database.sql file.There is one fiel generated database.sq.IO ned to copy this file to another pc and make all my records to insert.So how may i do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can import .sql file using the standard input like this:

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <dbname> < file.sql
```

**Note:** There shouldn't space between -p and password

Comment: how may i increase my reputation???? its very low :/ ...you upvote me...

Comment: you can vote me also to increase my reputation. Thanks

Comment: ok i will.....if you dont mind....may i ask something.....means will you upvote in all my questions link.....whatever i have posted.....in all....thanks...