# How may i Switch my Rails App from Mysql to Sql Server in rails 4 in Windows

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-4

How may i change my database from MYSQL to Sql server in Rails 4

```html
 What configuration i may specify in database.yml file and what all gem i may need to add for that.Please help. :)
```

Comment: theres no link in googe for this so please help.

Comment: i have seen sql-adapter gem.But dont know how to use it.

Comment: but i want data from previous mysql database to be present in sql server also.None of my data may be deleted.

Comment: 1. mysqldump -h [host] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name < db_backup.sql 2.source db_backup.sql   but what is the second command in case for sql server??????????????????

Comment: there is .sql file generated in mysql now i want to move all this data to sqlserver database using ruby on rails.

Comment: on runninhg dump command .sql file was generated,now i want to move all this data to sqlserver database.

Comment: my previous account was suspended....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `gemfile`

```
gem install mysql2
```

And this to `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_db_name
  username: YOUR_USER_NAME
  password: YOUR_PASSWORD 

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_db_name
  username: YOUR_USER_NAME
  password: YOUR_PASSWORD

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production_db_name
  username: YOUR_USER_NAME
  password: YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Mysql2 is already installed,only problem is i have created dump file of database using mysql2 database.Now i changed my database from mysql to sqlserver.Now i want to restore that .sql dump file to sql server database.But how may i do it.....coz source dump_file_name.sql is an mysql command for restoring....but now i want to restore that dump file in sql server database....then how its possible?????? please let me know.......!!!!

Comment: my previous a/c is suspended.....you helped me in this question......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4....u remembered??????