# Syntax in MySQL for date in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I used SQLite3 as my database, but now I changed it to MySQL. There is one line in my code which is failing now. What is the syntax for MySQL?

```
<% year = os.ot_daily_date.strftime("%Y")%>
```

This line is showing the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION hrms_development.strftime
does not exist: SELECT `overtime_daily_records`.* FROM `overtime_daily_records`
GROUP BY strftime('%Y',ot_daily_date)):
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4) help?

Comment: Can you please add what os object is?

Comment: @anu jainThere is no strftime function in MySQL. Use DATE_FORMAT instead.

Comment: @Dnyanarthlonkar DATE_FORMAT is not working on index page .

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<% year = os.ot_daily_date.year %>
```

Explain: `os.ot_daily_date` will return a `Date` value if `ot_daily_date` have `date` data type in your Mysql database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you show me the result of `os.ot_daily_date.class`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% year = os.ot_daily_date.to_date.year %>
```

Comment: 1) the supplied error message does not support your hypothesis. 2) rails does __not__ turn everything into strings first time it sees an object. So `os.ot_daily_date` (prior to calling `strftime` on it) would be in no way affected by rails view rendering.

Comment: Now the answer lacks explanation. What do you think the problem is, and why this code should help?